# calculate partition from two table and using index less than or equals of index in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have 2 table, first table is a main table that i want to join and sum partition to second table.

the first table is : main_table

| Month | Product | MOB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | B2B | 1 |
| 2020-12-01 | B2B | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | B2B | 1 |
| 2020-11-01 | B2C | 1 |
| 2020-11-01 | B2C | 2 |
| 2020-11-01 | B2C | 3 |

second table is : second_table

| month | Product | MOB | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | B2B | 0 | 100 |
| 2020-12-01 | B2B | 2 | 100 |
| 2021-01-01 | B2B | 1 | 50 |
| 2020-11-01 | B2C | -2 | 50 |
| 2020-11-01 | B2C | 1 | 55 |
| 2020-11-01 | B2C | 3 | 100 |

my expectation result is

| Month | Product | MOB | partition_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | B2B | 1 | 100 |
| 2020-12-01 | B2B | 2 | 200 |
| 2021-01-01 | B2B | 1 | 50 |
| 2020-11-01 | B2C | 1 | 105 |
| 2020-11-01 | B2C | 2 | 105 |
| 2020-11-01 | B2C | 3 | 205 |

how to calculate partition_amount is when main_table.Month=second_table.Month and main_table.product=second_table.product and the partition is sum of second_table.amount by mob. it would be calculate when second_table.mob <= main_table.mob

anyone can help me to write the query use big query ?

Answer (score 0):

> it would be calculate when second_table.mob <= main_table.mob

One method is `join` and aggregation:

```
select m.month, m.product, m.mob, sum(s.partition_amount)
from main_table m join
     second_table s
     on s.month = m.month and
        s.product = m.product and
        s.mob <= m.mob
group by 1, 2, 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select any_value(main_table).*,
  sum(if(second_table.mob <= main_table.mob, amount, 0)) as partition_amount
from `project.dataset.main_table` main_table
left join `project.dataset.second_table` second_table
using(month, product)
group by format('%t', main_table)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]